# Why are non-English company pages allowed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, english

I was just looking into the jobs section, and I stuck with this page. It is non-English.

Non-English posts are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Then why is Stack Overflow allowing creation of non-English company pages?

[image]

[Link to the page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/143071/software-analyst-m-f-open-xchange-gmbh?so=p&sec=False&pg=4&offset=17)

Comment: Why would they **not** be allowed to be localised to where the job is going to be?

Comment: I'm not sure I see a problem here.  Jobs is meant to be international anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is a remote job. And I think it will be good if it is in English.

Comment: @SagarV: that's up for that company to decide, not us.

Comment: @SagarV Stonk! :-=)

Comment: @SagarV If internal communication in the company is in german, you should better be able to speak german - at least well enough to understand the job description. if you don't you are likely a bad fit for the position anyways. So, let the company decide what they want.

Comment: Stack Overflow main only uses English because everyone is supposed to be able to read and interact with posts. The Jobs site doesn't need every job seeker to be able to interact with every job posting.

Comment: Beginning to think OP goes into a panic if he hasn't asked a mega-downvoted meta question at least once a day.

Answer (score 11):

Jobs are *not questions on Stack Overflow*. The language rules of questions and answers do not apply.

The jobs site itself is actually localised, and companies are presented with an interface in their own language:

- US English: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent
- UK English: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/uk/talent
- German: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/de/talent
- French: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/fr/talent

So we certainly wouldn't want to then require the company posting an advert in English when they post about a job in France in an otherwise entirely French site.

Also,

- Companies *pay* for those listings, and they get to have a lot more say about how that is presented
- No volunteer time is wasted in handling those posts (an important reason why we require SO questions to be in English)
- Companies usually expect people to be local, or if remote, to be familiar with the local 'culture' (which can include speaking their language)

Comment: is there an option available for us to filter out non english pages?

Comment: @SagarV: I'm not aware of any such option.